# I'm making a clicker game and im trying to use the js to change the text in a <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a clicking game and im using js too but im trying to change text in a

tag and for some reason it keeps not changing i think it might also be the button too because it says that getMoney is not defined when i click it but i did define it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>clicker game V0.1</title>
  <style>
    button {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      color: #ccc;
      background-color: #555;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#888, #555);
      background: linear-gradient(#888, #555);
      border: 0 none;
      border-radius: 3px;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666, 0 5px 0 #444, 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    h1 {
      color: #0061ff;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: helvetica;
      font-size: 1.75em;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #3d3d3d;
    }
    .intergers {
      position: relative;
    }
    p {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: helvetica;
      font-size: 1.25em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var money = 0;
    var moneyPC = 1;

    function getMoney() {
      money += moneyPC;
    }
    setInterval(function shows() {
      var mone = document.getElementById("money_show")
      document.getElementById("money_show").innerHTML = money;
    }, 50)
    }
  </script>
  <h1>Aquire</h1>
  <p id="money_show" class="intergers">0</p>
  <p>dollars</p>
  <button onClick="getMoney()">$$$</button>
  <br>
  <h1>Upgrade</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Dankbeats! Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) I'm seeing a syntax error in your code.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use jQuery?

Comment: @TonyHensler I see no compelling reason to use jquery here. There is a simple select on id, which is handled easy enough with straight javascript.

Comment: @JonP maybe thats true for this little section of code we have seen here, but for his upgrades in the next section and any other sections that are going to be created, it would save a lot of coding time.

Comment: You have a simple syntax error. As pointed out by Mike C, use the error console and you will see your problem. Loose the last `}` and your problem will be solved. The error console, and console it self is an important tool to learn how to use when debugging javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Better implementation of the same.

```
<script>
    var money = 0;
    var moneyPC = 1;
    var moneyshow = document.getElementById("money_show");
    function getMoney(){
        money += moneyPC;
        moneyshow.innerHTML = money;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The OP question example would trigger a undefined element error since the anonymous function is already calling the tags.

Comment: @Carlitos: OP doesn't use the variable `mone` anyways. I was wondering why he defined it in the first place.